# Temporary tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on creation of temporary tables in sql server. I created the temporary table successfully but when I try to view the data it says INVALID OBJECT NAME.
Can anyone pls tell foe how long temporary tables exists? 
If I am logged on to sql server as userid - devloper and pwd = 0999 and someother person is also logged on to the sql server with same credentials, this temporary tables will get deleted?
my sql is as follows:

```
SELECT net_node_model.SYS_ID, net_node_model.NODE, mst_temp_equation.TEMP_ID,
       mst_temp_equation.EQ_ID
INTO ##NT_MASTER_TEMP_EQUATION
FROM mst_temp_equation INNER JOIN
     net_node_model ON mst_temp_equation.TEMP_ID = net_node_model.TEMP_ID
GROUP BY net_node_model.SYS_ID, net_node_model.NODE, mst_temp_equation.TEMP_ID,
         mst_temp_equation.EQ_ID, mst_temp_equation.EQ_NAME,
         mst_temp_equation.EQ_TYPE, mst_temp_equation.[OBJECT],
         mst_temp_equation.VAR_TYPE, mst_temp_equation.VAR_NAME,
         mst_temp_equation.VAR_SUBSET, mst_temp_equation.VAR_SET,
         mst_temp_equation.RHS_RELN, mst_temp_equation.RHS_OBJECT,
         mst_temp_equation.RHS_VAR_SET, mst_temp_equation.RHS_VAR_SUBSET,
         mst_temp_equation.RHS_VAR_TYPE, mst_temp_equation.RHS_VAR_NAME,
         mst_temp_equation.EQ_TP_OFFSET, mst_temp_equation.RHS_TP_OFFSET,
         mst_temp_equation.RETAIN, mst_temp_equation.TIME_PRD,
         mst_temp_equation.EQ_VAR_SUBTYPE, mst_temp_equation.RHS_VAR_SUBTYE;
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL that you are using?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using a regular temporary table `#table`, it will not be visible to any other session apart from the one it was created on. Once that session is finished, the table will be removed.

If you are using a global temporary table `##table`, it will be visible to other sessions.

From MSDN - [`CREATE TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx), under `temporary tables`:

> Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the session that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped referencing them.

Comment: I am not sure whether I use # or ## if I try to select records from my tem table using select query it says INVALID OBJECT NAME

Comment: @us111 - if the session it was created on was finished and the table is not referenced by any other running tasks, it will be automatically dropped.

Comment: I have not closed the session...I am doing some testing so first I run stored procedure 1 which create temp table1 and then immediately I try to execute select query to see the records it says INVALID OBJECT NAME.

Comment: @us111 - Once the stored procedure has finished executing, the session has finished.

Comment: oh ok...so If I have number of stored procedures which needs to be executed sequentially...How can i do this?

Comment: @us111 - Run them all in one transaction, or call them from one stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you have already created the ##NT_MASTER_TEMP_EQUATION table, and are now trying to insert into it?  If so, use the syntax `INSERT INTO ##NT_MASTER_TEMP_EQUATION SELECT ...` instead of what you have.

`SELECT ... INTO ##temp FROM ...` is used to both create the table AND populate it.

Additionally, you have a rogue `,` at the end of your `SELECT` list (just before the keyword `INTO`).  This should be removed.

Comment: the ',' is typo...its not there in actual query. Yes I am creating and inserting the records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the exact query you used, then I think you may have a syntax error on the first line, looks like there is an extra comma right before the keyword `INTO`

```
...mst_temp_equation.EQ_ID,  INTO ##NT_MASTER_TEMP_EQUATION
                          ^
```

Not sure if this is causing the INVALID OBJECT NAME error or not

Comment: sorry there is a typo there is no ',' after EQ_ID

Answer (score 0):

Here seems you have created global temporary table. Note that Global temporary tables are useful when you want the result set visible to all other sessions. No need to setup permissions. Anyone can insert values, modify, or retrieve records from the table. Also note that anyone can DROP the table.

And once the session disconnects these tables get dropped automatically.