# SQL Server Temp Tables across multiple scripts/tabs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I read a quote from Zed Shaw once that said something like "if a software developer writes the same code more than once, he should write a function so he doesn't have to repeat himself".

On a daily basis, I find myself making temp tables in `SQL Server` more than once per day.  I don't need these tables to live past midnight each day which is why I chose to use a temp table.  However, I have various scripts in different tabs in `SQL Management Studio` - I have to repeat these temp tables in every one of the scripts in order to reference it, and this seems quite inefficient.  My ultimate goal would be to run a stored procedure that would populate multiple temp tables and have them available to run my analyses.

Is there a better way to reference the tables than my current usage?  Is there a way to reference the temp tables across all sessions in `SQL Server 2008`?

Comment: You could make them permenant tables, but create a job to delete the data from them each night (and you populate them when you need them)?

Comment: @Bridge - That's definitely an option.  I think I was trying to avoid based on some fear of commitment that plagues me through-out my life....  Permanent tables might be the way to go....

Comment: Do you know the `##TempTable` type of temp table?. Seems to be what you want. Its a global temporary table. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Temporary tables in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258651/temporary-tables-in-sql-server)

Comment: Since you're using SQL Server 2008, you could try [passing table valued parameters](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/168). The limitation of this is that they would need to be read only - you'd only need to create it once and pass it to all of your stored procedures.

Comment: @Lamak I think your solution would work perfectly.  Submit that as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks for info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that what you want are [global temporary tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). The syntax to use them is the same as normal temporary tables, but they have two `##` instead of one (`##temptable`). Please take a look at the link first to know the limitations of them.